# How can I use a USBC DisplayPort monitor with my 12” MacBook and charge at the same time?

Tags: macbook-pro, usb, peripheral

I was hoping to get an Asus MB169C+ monitor to increase my screen real estate while traveling and working on my 12” MacBook.

However, I'm confused as to how I can charge my MacBook and use the display at the same time? I expect to have it setup for extended periods while traveling and would prefer not to run everything off the battery whenever I want to use the monitor.

Is this even possible? It seems like I would need some way of splitting power and also the usbc to DisplayPort connection, but continually more concerned at how limiting this single port system is.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you intend to use the Asus MB169C+ while also charging your MacBook, you will need an adaptor, hub, dock, etc.

Here are some examples for you:

- [Hub+](https://www.nonda.co/products/usb-c-hub-for-apple-new-macbook-12-plus)
- [Kadi Port](https://kadicreative.com/products/the-kadi-port)
- [Arc Hub](https://www.bourgedesign.com)

**NOTE:** I have not used any of these personally - I have linked to them just to provide some examples of how you can achieve what you want. However, there are many products that will meet your needs varying from cheap to expensive.

Comment: Ok so I suppose that is the solution although at this point only one of those devices (the Kadi Port) is shipping, and I'd have to find out if DisplayPort functionality is maintained through the hub. Perhaps it's indeed a matter of waiting until these hubs become more ubiquitous.

Comment: Yes, if you intend to still go with the Asus MB169C+. Basically there are lots of options for you if you're using a display with a typical 'display' connection (e.g. HDMI, Thunderbolt, etc). In your case you'd have to make sure any adapter, hub, etc has a USB-C port supporting “DP Alt Mode” or “DisplayPort over USB-C” capability, and that it **also** provides power capability so the Asus MB169C+ can power up!

Answer (score 1):

I just signed up to say that the answer by Monomeeth is almost certainly incorrect.

The "Hub+" and "Arc Hub" definitely *will not* work because to charge the device, it will need 1x USB-C to MacBook, 1x USB-C to charger, and a third USB-C to connect to the USB-C monitor. They only have 2x USB-C on the adapter.

The "Kadi Port" *might* work, but it is highly doubtful, because it has another HDMI port on board. Aside from HDMI requiring active protocol conversion from DisplayPort (adding to cost and complexity), that would also require that there be a DisplayPort MST hub inside, and for the cost, that is highly unlikely.

I am interested in solving this, because it will allow me to use it with my Galaxy S8 / S8+ on the go without draining its battery.

I have a heap of USB-C female breakout PCBs that I ordered off Ebay. When I get more time, I will connect four of them together. It will be that the two main ports will be connected together with all pins except power and CC (TX, RX, D+, D-, SBU). The power and CC lines will be connected to their corresponding charging ports. I don't know if it will work, or if it is safe. But I am getting desperate. I cannot believe that not a single company has identified this niche market. I have looked extensively.

I have solved the problem of how to connect a normal DisplayPort computer without USB-C to the Asus MB169C+ - but it is not pretty. It involves using a Sunix UPD2018, and building an enclosure to power it through the PCIe x1 bus - tested and proof of concept on YouTube. But this does not solve the power problem.

I am sorry, but to the best of my knowledge, the correct answer is, at least for the time being, that there is no solution.

Best of luck!